# unable installing php extensions from source

Tags: php

I installed php 5.3.10 from source and it runs fine. But when i tried to install extensions from source packages like `xdebug` and `mongo` i get the following output after running `phpize`

```
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
```

Notice that these are just warnings not failure. So i continued and used `./configure` and then `make` and then `make install`. A message came like this

```
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20090626/
```

I checked in the above directory and the extension's shared object(.so) was there. So i added the path to my `php.ini` and restarted apache. **But the extension is not installed.**

I googled it and found that the warnings come because the `phpize`  path is not correct. I checked this by
`phpize --help` and it shows the path `/usr/local/bin/phpize`

also php-config version is 5.3.10
`php-config -v` and it shows `version 5.3.10`

Whats wrong and what is meant by those warnings?

**EDIT:**
When i try to install these extension from `pecl` i can install them successfully and i can see them installed in the output of `phpinfo()`

But i cant install `mcrypt` via pecl so i need some way of installing extensions using `phpize`

Comment: Does your php.ini have the right value for ext_dir? Also try to run php -m from command line

Comment: @Jack the value for `extension_dir` is commented out and php -m showed xdebug and mongo after i installed them from pecl. But what does `extension_dir` has to do with the warning. Also i am using complete disk path of extensions in my php.ini

Comment: Doesn't mcrypt come with php itself? As in, it's a ./configure option I believe.

Comment: yes but i have to recompile php for that. But the point is why that warning comes and why cant i install extensions that way. I have previously installed extensions this way on my previous system and it used to work fine

Comment: If the .so file is there and it's in the php.ini you should get startup warnings. Perhaps check with display_startup_errors=On

Comment: I do get startup warnings for extensions not installed via pecl

Comment: Care to share those startup warnings in your question then? That's actually pretty important information :)

Comment: I dont know how but i am able to install extensions successfully now. I still get that warning but extensions are installed

Answer (score 3):

i know it's a old question, but to solve this problem, just run the command `./configure` with the option `"--with-php-config"`.

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
```